# Finding and batch editing HTML elements' content in Sublime Text 2

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I would like to replace link texts using regex in sublime text 2

my links look like this

```
<a href="#" class="link link1">This is a text for link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link link2">This is a text for link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link link3">This is a text for link 3</a>
```

I have more than 100 links in my page.

I have tried regex like this.

```
<a href="#" class="link.+">.+</a>
```

It works But it match the tags too.

Can anyone tell me how to match only this text `This is a text for link *` ?

Comment: You want to match any text between each pair of opening and closing tags for links?

Comment: @NaveedS Yes I want to match any text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I don't know why you only want to match the text, though. I can hardly think of any use case where that might be necessary. Usually capturing groups would be sufficient for most replacement scenarios.*

**If the text within the tag doesn't have any pattern, and the tag can contain arbitrary classes**, then **NO**, it is **NOT possible** to do so. SublimeText seems to use Boost library, which doesn't support variable length look-behind.

If the tag are consistent (everything down to the spaces is the same), except for the link number in the `class` attribute, then it might be possible to certain extent:

```
(?<=<a href="#" class="link link\d">).+?(?=</a>)
```

If link followed by number class has 2 digits, you need to add in the corresponding look-behind:

```
(?:(?<=<a href="#" class="link link\d">)|(?<=<a href="#" class="link link\d\d">)).+?(?=</a>)
```

(`\d{1,2}` won't work in look-behind. The length is not finitely many, but the regex engine doesn't support it.)

[**Working screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gX6gj.png)

Comment: Hi thankyou. But I'm getting this error. `invalid lookbehind assertion encountered in the regular expression`

Comment: @Giri: What is your version of SublimeText? Mine is 2.0.1 build 2217. Check the screenshot.

Comment: I'm also using the same version. Actually my class not looking like link1, link2 etc. I just given that name for demo. But all my link class doesn't have digits in it. So I changed your code like this. `(?<=<a href="#" class="link.+?">).+?(?=</a>)` But still i'm getting this error. `invalid lookbehind assertion encountered in the regular expression` Is something wrong with the code or editor?

Comment: @Giri: Like I said in my post: my regex only works under that assumption. If your classes are arbitrary, it is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

As hinted by nhahtdh in his answer, you can do the replacement without using look-behind or look-ahead, use this regex to do replacement:

Search regex:

```
(<a href="#" class="link.+?">)[^<]+(\d)(</a>)
```

Replacement string:

```
\1Link number \2 has been replaced\3
```

That would replace this:

```
<a href="#" class="link link1">This is a text for link 1</a>
<a href="#" class="link link2">This is a text for link 2</a>
<a href="#" class="link link3">This is a text for link 3</a>
```

into this:

```
<a href="#" class="link link1">Link number 1 has been replaced</a>
<a href="#" class="link link2">Link number 2 has been replaced</a>
<a href="#" class="link link3">Link number 3 has been replaced</a>
```

The example I gave above also shows that it's possible to have capturing group in the anchor text matching, if you don't want it, you can remove it, and change the capturing group number accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

For matching **This is a text for link** followed by a space followed by a number, use `This is a text for link \d+`.

**Edit:** For matching any text between pair of opening and closing tags for links, use capture group like:

```
<a href="#" class="link.+?">(.+)</a>
```

`$1` matches the text in between the tags.

Comment: I think `This is a text for link` is only for demo, not the actual text.

Comment: I think you still didn't get what i'm asking. I'm using a text editor. I would like to change all anchor link text. The code you given select the whole tag. But i don't want to select the whole tag. Just the anchor text

Comment: @Giri In that case, you would have to use look behind as in the answer by nhahtdh . Does your editor support it?

Comment: @NaveedS: I have SublimeText 2 - that particular regex has not been tested, but it should work.